# Eloquent update method change created_at timestamp

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent for database handling, when I update a record with update method `created_at` time stamp is changed how to prevent this from happening ?

```
$post = Post::update([
   'name' => $name
]);
```

`updated_at` timestamp is working perfectly

Comment: Do you want to update all posts? What's the initial value of `created_at` for record you are updating?

Comment: no i'm updating certain record but that only for demonstrating, initial value is 2015-12-23 00:24:53 after update  2015-12-27 05:29:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't have any custom settings in your model. You can update record like this:

```
$id = 5; // here put id of record you want to update
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$post->name = $name;
$post->save();
```

Using this code only `name` should be updated and `updated_at` timestamp (and not `created_at`). If `created_at` is also updated it means you might have some custom model settings or:

- you might have database triggers that change `created_at` when record is updated
- you might have registered some events that change `created_at` when record is updated
- make sure your `created_at` field in `posts` table in database is not defined as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - this way whenever you update record, `created_at` will be also updated to current datetime

You should also make sure that you don't have for your `Post` model something like this:

```
const UPDATED_AT = 'created_at';
```

If would also explain why `created_at` is changed when you update your record.

Comment: same thing. this is my model 
`code'
class Post extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'posts';

  protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'name_arabic',
    'tags',
    'tags_arabic',
    'category',
    'category_arabic',
    'content',
    'content_arabic',
    'post_thumb',
    'draft'
  ];

Comment: So as I said you need to verify database triggers and other actions in Laravel, because simple update won't update `created_at` column. Please make sure that `created_at` column in database is also only timestamp without setting `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on record update - you should not have something like this `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @user3266289 Could you please tell what the exact problem was?

Comment: created_at field is set to on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in my database

Comment: @user3266289 Thanks, sometimes the last guess is the best one ;)